# C#/.NET app running on IIS 6: set up redirect/reauth prompt after 15minute session

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, session-timeout

After 15 minutes, I would like the user to be re-prompted for their Active Directory UN and PW. 
In my web.config I added the following:

```
<sessionState timeout="15" />
```

The following was already in there:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"  />
```

The authentication mode is indeed Windows and say you were to go to this site for the first time ever, it would ask you for your Active Directory username and password. No issues authenticating there.

When I look at Session State for this website in IIS Manager, I see the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZJJb.jpg (posted it to Imgur so you can see the screenshot a bit easier instead of having to zoom in.

When I fire up Chrome Developer tools on the production website, `ASP.NET_SessionId` is set to an expiration date of `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z`. It is always set to this value.

From what I understand there is a difference between what is set in IIS Settings and what is set in `Web.config`

So what I'm wondering is if there's a conflict between what's in `Web.config` and what is in the IIS Settings. I would like after 15 minutes for the user to be prompted (again) for their Active Directory UN/PW.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Have you tried waiting longer than 15 minutes before making another request and seeing if it forces you to log in again? Remember, session state is on the server, so it doesn't really matter what the cookie in the browser says.

Comment: @GabrielLuci for testing purposes I set sessionstate timeout to `1` instead of `15` in `web.config` now in an attempt to replicate the login/logout behavior. in the IIS Session State Cookie Settings, I set Time-out to 1: https://imgur.com/a/VJ1K72p . Still nothing on prompting me to log in again.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript on the page making requests back to the server? The timeout will kick in only after there have been no requests made for that long.

Comment: Not that I'm seeing no. The JS in this application is pretty minimal and straight forward.

Comment: Wait, you're using Windows authentication. It's possible that it is actually expiring and the session *is* being recreated, but the browser is resending the credentials automatically. You can check the [`Session.IsNewSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.isnewsession) property to see if the session was actually recreated (either by debugging, or output the value to the page)

Comment: So using `IsNewSession` seems to be triggered correctly based on the 1min timeout value. But what I did (for now) is set the mode in Web.config to `InProc` and set up a `Session_OnEnd` method in Global.asax.cs, using `Application.Lock()`. Setting a breakpoint here is triggered every 1 min if there's no new requests, so that's good. Now to actually reauthenticate/reprompt for AD creds after the 1min instead of `Application.Lock()`.

Comment: If `Session_OnEnd` is triggering then the session *is* ending. I suspect the browser is resending credentials silently.

Comment: Hm, maybe it's because Anonymous authentication is enabled here and windows auth is disabled? https://imgur.com/a/HMt4VXu

Comment: That would do it - there is no authentication going on at all.

Comment: So messing with those settings didn't really change anything. As for no auth going on at all, there must be some since when you first load this site up (for the first time ever), it prompts AD auth?